# MergeSort TypeError between base case comparisons

Tags: python, mergesort

I am trying to implement a merge sort algorithm using python. I am sorting words and I am getting a confusing error. I was wondering if anyone here had any input or could be of any help.

The Code:

```
    def mergeSort(A, p, r):
        if p < r:
            q = [(p + r) / 2]
            mergeSort(A, p, q)
            mergeSort(A, q + 1, r)
            merge(A, p, q, r)
    
    def merge(A, p, q, r):
        n1 = q - p + 1
        n2 = r - q
        L = []
        R = []
        for i in range(n1):
            L.append(A[p + i - 1])
        for j in range(n2):
            R.append(A[q + j])
        L.append(infinity)
        R.append(infinity)
        i = 0
        j = 0
        for k in range(p,r):
            if L[i] <= R[j]:
                A[k] = L[i]
                i = i + 1
            else:
                A[k] = R[j]
                j = j + 1

testSortingList = ['joe', 'test', 'john', 'aaaa', 'a']
start = 0
end = 5
mergeSort(testSortingList, start, end)
print(testSortingList)
```

The Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "c:\Users\josep\OneDrive\Desktop\CS340_Project1\main.py", line 94, in <module>
    mergeSort(testSortingList, start, end)   File "c:\Users\josep\OneDrive\Desktop\CS340_Project1\main.py", line 27, in mergeSort
    mergeSort(A, p, q)   File "c:\Users\josep\OneDrive\Desktop\CS340_Project1\main.py", line 25, in mergeSort
    if p < r:
       ^^^^^ TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'list'
```

Comment: Did your indentation get altered in the process of pasting your code here? That wouldn't run as shown.

Comment: Use a debugger?

Comment: Yes it did, and I couldn't manage to fix it without it not showing up as a code block. None of the def should have an indentation. (Not too experienced with stackoverflow)

Comment: Okay, I figured out the comparison issue. q was being assigned to a list [(p+r) / 2], but now I just have infinite recursion?

Answer (score 0):

In your `mergeSort` function you assign

`q = [(p + r) / 2]`

which assigns one element list to q.

Then you call reqursivly `mergeSort` with `q`, which makes comparison between `p` - an int and `q` - instance of list.